# Azure Functions: Unable to swap from a deployment slot to production slot

Tags: azure-functions

Are there issues swapping slots with function apps? I seem to be unable to swap a deployment slot into the production slot. I can click the Swap button but then it tells me there are no slots to swap it with.

Answer (score 1):

There was a an issue in the portal that was preventing that from working. It should be [fixed now](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-ux/commit/6d22f8ca04dca93994601daa31b8e60b51338ed5). Can you give it another try.